# Google Apps Script: How to change text color of label on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script and am relativly new to it. I am wondering if there is a way to change the color of text for a label when hovering over it with a mouse? Like how sometimes hyperlinks change color when hovering over them. To be clear, this question is asking about how to do it with labels and not hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client handlers are made for this.  Try using `styleAttributes` and `MouseOver` / `mouseOutHandler` like in the example below. ([test code available here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwWBQtCvdNKxJTMmzxAM8CkReNIBfmR4KTlPZI8yfzBYv9VO9Q/exec))

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test hover');
  var label = app.createLabel('Hover test here');
  var handlerOver = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setStyleAttributes({'color':'red'});
  var handlerOut = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setStyleAttributes({'color':'black'});
  label.addMouseOverHandler(handlerOver).addMouseOutHandler(handlerOut);
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the mouseover and mouseout events to accomplish this, the below example should help you

```
     function doGet() {
       var app = UiApp.createApplication();
       var text = app.createTextBox().setName("text");
       text.addMouseOverHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setStyleAttribute("background-color", "yellow"));
       text.addMouseOutHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setStyleAttribute("background-color", "white"));    
       app.add(text);
       return app;
     }
```